# Is Silverlight much slower than Flash or is it the site?

Tags: silverlight, flash

I try to watch this video made in silverlight:
http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX10/EX15

Problem is after a few minutes it completely stops. Rarely happens with Flash.

What's the cause ? Slowness of Silverlight or is it the site ?

Comment: Did you try downloading it so you remove network latency from the mix?

Comment: Silverlight is not necessary slower, however, the internet being the volatile thing it is, you'd need exactly the same item, through flash and Silverlight off the same server, at the same time. to be sure.

Comment: Even then, they probably have relative speed advantages in different tasks. Unless one is simply better.

Comment: I believe Silverlight is supposed to be much better optimized for streaming HD content than Flash... so in theory it's faster, at least at decoding. Definitely hard to compare in real life, though, because the real aspect of "speed" here will be communications with the server, not anything occuring client side.